# Сайт с несуществующим url site.ru/index.php/... открывает главную страницу

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Существует сайт site.ru у него нет папки (index.php).

### При переходе на страницы site.ru/index.php/....(site.ru/index.php/4, site.ru/index.php/sdsasasf и т.д.) переходит на главную страницу.

Страницы не существующие.
Ошибка 404, 410 присутствует на сайте.

Существует папка (index).
Ридирект site.ru/index.php на site.ru есть.

Нужно убрать ридирект, сам его не прописывал.

Comment: Что за движок? Нужно код смотреть

Comment: вы прям мастер формулировать мысли.

Comment: @user190134 Сайт без движка... Подключен через cloudflare, есть стереть весь код в htaccess, проблема остается, скорее всего нужно что-то дописать..

Comment: @teran Cпасибо, старался.

Comment: dropmefiles.com/0qhhw [Cсылка на htaccess файл в формате .txt]